# Transform (rotate) background image with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a menu system where when you click on a link, sub-headings will slide down beneath them. I have this fine, however I want to add an arrow, set as a background image to list items, that animatedly rotates 90 degrees when active. So, my question is as follows: How can I transform (rotate) a background image without rotating the whole list item?

Cheers,
BlackWraith

Comment: Can you use a pseudo element? Then rotate that with css or js?

Comment: What do you mean by that exactly?

Comment: Wasn't able to work out what I thought made sense. a:after { background ... } a:after:hover { rotate... }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can just rotate the background-image by itself. 
What you have to do is declare another `<span style="display:block;width:16px;height:16px; background:url(my_arrow.png);">` element inside your `<li>` and then rotate the whole `<span>`.

Usually people just use a single sprite and background-position to change the arrow from ► to ▼ in nested lists.

Comment: Thanks, and a single sprite does sound a lot simpler.. I'll give it a shot :)

Comment: Sorry for the extraly slow reply, I kind of forgot to get back to it. A sprite worked perfectly. :)